# Display LocalStorage value

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I want to display LocalStorage value in my html using vueJS but I am unable to get the value.

I am getting this error `Uncaught (in promise) ReferenceError: currentCategory is not defined`

```html
<h3 class="meal-title">Recettes de {{ this.currentCategory }}</h3>
```

```js
var categoryStorage = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("currentCategory"));
data() {
    return {
      meals: [],
      categories: [],
      currentCategory: currentCategory
    }
  },
```

Comment: Is it typo , maybe `currentCategory: categoryStorage`

Comment: you could check in developer console first whether that item truly exists or not

Comment: changed typo, still not working. I think i have to do something like that document.getElementsByClassName('meal-title').innerHTML = `<h3>${categoryStorage}</h3>` but wont work too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should assign `categoryStorage` into a `currentCategory`.

Live Demo **:**

```js
var categoryStorage = 'A'; // You can get the value from local storage here

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data() {
    return {
      meals: [],
      categories: [],
      currentCategory: categoryStorage
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <h3 class="meal-title">Recettes de {{ currentCategory }}</h3>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
<h3 class="meal-title">Recettes de {{ currentCategory }}</h3>
```

```
export default {
    data() {
        return {
            meals: [],
            categories: [],
            currentCategory: null,
        };
    },

    // mounted
    mounted() {
        this.currentCategory = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('currentCategory'));
    },
};
```

Comment: I get this error ```Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: this.currentCategory is not a function```

Comment: I've just updated the answer now check.